# Magento - Not able to resolve - jQuery / jCarousel Conflict Issue

Tags: magento, jcarousel, jquery

I am trying all ways possible to resolve the JQuery Conflict issue in magento. Verified a few forums too but of no help.

I have tried the following:
1.Added jQuery.noConflict(); at the end of the jquery files (still didnt work)
2.Created a variable for noConflict and used all functions  (still didnt work)

I can see the Js and CSS files required for jCarousel to function in the output source code, however along with that i get the following error:

```
jQuery("#mycarousel").jcarousel is not a function

Line 80
```

Not sure what I'm missing.

I am a newbie to magento. Is there a possibility that I'm missing on some important files to update.

Please assist as soon as possible.

I'm Following the examples of JCarousel as closely as possible. It works fine without Magento, but in Magento error as mentioned above is returned.

Comment: do you load jquery.jcarousel.min.js?

Comment: and make sure that your jcarousel script uses jQuery instead of $

Comment: yes, i tried both the recommendations still there is an issue

Answer (score 0):

Check out the view source and make sure that the JCariusel scripts are inserted after JQuery.

Comment: Did that too, however the issue still persists :( please help

Comment: jQuery(document).ready(function() {
//jQuery("#mycarousel").hide();
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery("#mycarousel").jcarousel({
//test
});
});

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, the it would not load within the magento site. I did however figure it out. I found that my code:

```
jQuery(".time_slider").jCarouselLite({
        btnNext: ".next_time",
        btnPrev: ".prev_time",
        circular: false,
        visible: 4,
        speed:1000
});
```

Was not being loaded into the theme due to it not having a

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {}
```

I also made sure that the jcarousel had a no conflict within the file and that it was loaded before the slider itself in the page.xml file.

Hope this helps. I also found that i had trouble with my no conflict in jQuery. If this doesn't help that is where the problem lies.